# change element size in drop-zone with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I want to drag an item from a container `A` to a container `B`. In my context the same item has a different size and style when it's in container `B` as opposed to container `A`.

[image]

I found an approach to do this but the issue is that the transforms on the items in container `B` to make room for the item while dragging are calculated based on the initial size in container `B`. Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

```
...
const isDraggingOverContainerB = snapshots.draggingOver === 'containerB';
const size = isDraggingOverContainerB ? 20 : 100;
return (
    <DraggableItem
       { ...provided.draggableProps }
       { ...provided.dragHandleProps }
       ref={ provided.innerRef }
       className={ 'drag-box' }
       style={{
           ...provided.draggableProps.style,
           width: size,
           height: size,
       }}
    />
)
```

Comment: Hello, did you solve this? I am looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide individual styling to the items in each container. You must have something like this:

```
<Dropabble className="containerA">
    <Draggable className="dragabbleItem">
    <Draggable>
</Dropabble>

<Dropabble className="containerB">
    <Draggable className="dragabbleItem">
    <Draggable>
</Dropabble>
```

You can have style like:

```
.containerA .dragabbleItem {
   width: 100px
}

.containerB .dragabbleItem {
   width: 20px
}
```